# Ruby (Savon) persistent SSL session?

Tags: ruby, ssl, savon

I am developing an application that connects in multiple threads to SSL secured SOAP service using Savon.

One of the requirements is to use persistent SSL connection.

"Googling" around gives no meaningful results.. except notice about net-http-persistent gem.

But HTTPI does not support it yet.

I thought curb should handle that by default... but it doesn't (according to ssl_engine logs which were sent to me after some tests).

Net::HTTP seems to create new ssl handshake on every request too.

Is there some existing solution to this?
Or should I write adapter for net-http-persistent for httpi to use it with savon?
The problem is that I don't know if it will work then and no one seems to have this problem.

Or... should I use stunnel (which is made for persistent connections)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

savon >= 2.3.0 works with httpi (2.1.0), which has an adapter for net-http-persistent. Then

```
require 'net/http/persistent'
HTTPI.adapter = :net_http_persistent
```

should do.

Comment: :) well, at the time when I needed it, it wasn't available. But thanks, I'm glad to see they got to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used net-http-persistent and wrote my httpi adapter for it.